# Asp.net PreRenderComplete taking a long time to finish

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm having an issue with occassional slow performance on button click events on a particular page. There are times that it performs well within normal parameters, but it seems like whenever the server is under even moderate load(meaning I can produce this issue in our production environment not in our dev or test environments) it seems to just hang.   After enabling tracing I see that it seems to just hang between the Begin PreRenderComplete and End PreRenderComplete.  It just sits there for close to 30 sec.  I don't have any specific code that executes in that event space.  My understanding was that this event is supposed to be a non event in the life cycle since it is just to make sure that the PreRender phase finished. This page has a large number of controls and as such has a sizable viewstate, but my understanding is that the view state is handled in the LoadState and SaveState events which don't seem to be the phases eating all of my time.

I've run perfmon against the server, and at times when I am able to produce this behavior system resources are normal, there aren't requests queuing.  I'm trying to understand what actions might be taking place behind the scenes causing this slowness.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any asynchronous actions on the page? I think that async calls will complete prior to that event, so if some of them are taking a while, such as a slow database or slow network call, that might cause the delay you're seeing.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything on the page that looks like an async action.  Are you saying that an async event would process during the PreRenderComplete phase?

Comment: @user1778199 I believe that async events will complete *before* PreRenderComplete, which, if I'm right, might indicate that a slow async request is "holding up" that event. But if there's no async, that might not be it.

Comment: That's what I thought for the time of the async events, but the odd part is my time is between Begin PreRenderComplete and End PreRenderComplete which unless I have specific code should be doing next to nothing during that phase correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the problem.  Through more indepth profiling it seems that my ScriptManager control was causing the delay in trying to combine scripts.  Apparently this only presented a problem under load and most take place in the prerendercomplete event.  By setting the  CombineScripts="false" attribute it seems to have cleared this issue.

Comment: How exactly did you set `CombineScripts="false"`?